# svg.js bbox() returns the same values after scale()

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

```
var SVGElement = SVG('elementId');
var group = SVGElement.group().path('M50,49.67a18.5,18.5,0,1,0-18.5-18.5A18.52,18.52,0,0,0,50,49.67Zm0-31a12.5,12.5,0,1,1-12.5,12.5A12.51,12.51,0,0,1,50,18.67Z')

bbox_beforeScale = group.bbox()
group.scale(2)
bbox_afterScale = group.bbox()

bbox_beforeScale == bbox_afterScale // true
```

BBox function call not calculating updated position, height and width

Comment: That’s how it’s supposed to work

Comment: You could call getBoundingClientRect instead or put the text in a container g element and get the container bounds

Comment: There is no `bbbox()` function in SVG.js.  Did you mean `bbox()`?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau That was a typo, I removed it.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Robert's comments, the SVG `getBBox()` method - which svg.js will be using under the hood of `bbox()` - returns the bounding box of the element. But it disregards any `transform` on that element.

To get the bounding box **after** the transform, you would need to wrap the element in a group, and call `getBBox()` (`bbox()`) on that.

In your case, you are already wrapping the path in a group. But the thing you are calling `group` is actually the path, not the group.

Try something like this:

```
var group = SVGElement.group();
var path = group.path(..);

bbox_beforeScale = group.bbox();
path.scale(2);
bbox_afterScale = group.bbox();
```

```js
var SVGElement = SVG('elementId');
var group = SVGElement.group();
var path = group.path('M50,49.67a18.5,18.5,0,1,0-18.5-18.5A18.52,18.52,0,0,0,50,49.67Zm0-31a12.5,12.5,0,1,1-12.5,12.5A12.51,12.51,0,0,1,50,18.67Z');

bbox_beforeScale = group.bbox();
path.scale(2);
bbox_afterScale = group.bbox();

// draw bbox
SVGElement.rect(bbox_afterScale.width, bbox_afterScale.height).addClass('box').move(bbox_afterScale.x, bbox_afterScale.y);
```

```css
path {
  fill: #f06;
}

.box {
  fill: none;
  strokeWidth: 1;
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/master/dist/svg.min.js"></script>

<div id="elementId"></div>
```